# How to resolve 'Cannot get 'Foreground' value' error when upgrading WPF .NET 4.7 app to .NET 7.0?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I have upgraded WPF .net 4.7 app to support .net 7.0 and getting the below run time error:

> {"Cannot get 'Foreground' value (type 'Brush') from '' (type 'Button'). BindingExpression:Path=Foreground; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'ImageAwesome' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Foreground'.\r\n   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, RequestFlags requests)\r\n   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueEntry(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, RequestFlags requests)\r\n   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)\r\n   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)\r\n   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'"}

How to resolve it?

I was expecting it comes due to below warning but did not found any alternative 'FontAwesome.WPF 4.7.0.9' to use in .net 7.0. The same package works fine in .net 4.7 before upgrade to .net 7.0

> Package 'FontAwesome.WPF 4.7.0.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?